# Power Automate - Approve but with more questions

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, approval-process

I'm trying to use 365 forms/automate and sharepoint online to forfill an approval process.

So we have a form. T Then that form goes to the users manager for approval. The manager before they can approve the managers needs to answer a few more questions. They might forward it to another person (reassignment).

Once all approved then it can go into a sharepoint list.

Is this possible using Microsoft forms and the automate proces? I've created a form and set up a power automate process which then sends approval email/message. So kinda there.

On the whole I'm impressesed but I guess the issue is that it does seem like you can change the approval page with any additonal questions aside for the comments box. You can only add in some details to the page. There isn't any option for custom questions.

So has anyone done anything similar to this? Is it 'just not possible'.

Just reading some blogs from July 2022
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-forms/can-multiple-users-fill-out-the-same-form/m-p/1144331
and doesn't look like this is possible.

But willing to be proved wrong.

Comment: Do a search for "Power Automate Approvals with Adaptive Cards". I haven't tried doing this myself, but I it may be what you're looking for.

Comment: You seem to be on something here.
https://adaptivecards.io/samples/Inputs.html
I'll have a play - thanks for putting me on to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are 3 answers to this, aside from the 'not possible'. Neither really do what I'm looking for and you have tradeoffs/issues in all.

So you start with the standard form and then in flow you have basically 2 choices.

**Option1**

Approval process. In this process you basically use the start and wait for an approval. This sends an email and teams messages that you can approve, reject or reassign.

The downside is that you can't ask any questions - aside from the comments box.
There are some details and items you can link in so that's useful.

**Option 2**

Adaptive cards.
This is sending a teams call and you send a card with questions and approve/reject buttons. It's really quite good however you can't do the reassigning and whist the Approval process can be reassigned as well as send an email - this your basically locked in to you and you can't reassign.

**Option 3**

Is laid out here - https://www.bythedevs.com/post/multi-line-approvals-with-adaptive-cards-outlook-and-power-automate

But you will need a premium licence which I don't have (at present).
But the instructions look sound and hence I'm adding it as an answer.

You could (in theory) forward the email form to another person thus forwarding it on. It's probably the best solution - too bad the http is premium.

Comment: Option 3 is here.
https://www.bythedevs.com/post/multi-line-approvals-with-adaptive-cards-outlook-and-power-automate
Which might just solve it all... given you could forward the email?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge and search，You cannot have more than one person complete the same survey response.

Using Microsoft forms and automating the process should not be possible.

Comment: Thanks Xyza - I'm a touch of a noob on the subject so kinda wanted someone to check / weigh in. And make sure that I'm not missing anything. Perhaps the question is more like linking two forms together then?